# *ngIf condition going in infinite loop

Tags: angular, observable, angular-ng-if

I have a button which I want to hide/show based on some condition for which I wrote *ngIf, but it is going in an infinite loop.

```
<b class="btn btn_draft" *ngIf="(!isAuthority) && isDisabled(application)" (click)="routeToDraftForm(application)">
                      {{application?.applicationSubmissionStatus | status}}
                    </b>
                    <b class="btn btn_draft" *ngIf="(isAuthority) && isDisabled(application)" (click)="routeToDraftForm(application)">
                    {{application?.applicationSubmissionStatus | status}}
                  </b>
```

Below is the .ts file

```
isDisabled(application: any) {
    console.log(application);
    let isValid = false;
    let formCreatedBy = '';
    this.preArrivalNotificationService.getById(application.applicationSubmissionId).subscribe((data: PreArrivalApplication) => {
      formCreatedBy = data.createdBy;
      const currentLoginId = sessionStorage.getItem('loginId');
      this.userWithCompanyInfoService.getBySearchCriteria('logonId:' + formCreatedBy, null, null, null).subscribe(res => {
        if (currentLoginId === formCreatedBy || this.currentUserCompanyUEN === res.content.companyUEN) {
          isValid = true;
        }
      });
    });
    return isValid;
  }
```

Comment: ngIf keeps on checking if the value has changed. So, it will keep on running and is expected behaviour.

Comment: It is happening because of this line `this.preArrivalNotificationService.getById(application.applicationSubmissionId).subscribe((data: PreArrivalApplication)`

Comment: How to resolve it?